# C++ 11 unordered_map segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

So I keep getting a segmentation fault when I run this with multiple threads:

```
class InvertedIndex {
private:
    unordered_map<string, Details> index;
    mutex indexInsert;

public:
  void addTerms(pair<string, list<string>> parsedReport) {
    unordered_map<string, Details>::iterator indexIterator;

        for (auto term = parsedReport.second.begin(); term != parsedReport.second.end(); ++term) {
            indexInsert.lock();
            indexIterator = index.find(*term);

            if (indexIterator == index.end()) {
                Details details;
                details.addOccurrence(parsedReport.first);
                index.insert(pair <string, Details> (*term, details));
            } else
                indexIterator->second.addOccurrence(parsedReport.first);

            indexInsert.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the program with GDB, it tells me that the problem is with index.find(*term), something to do with the hashing. It runs fine when I run it with a single thread which I find strange because I have locks around it.

---

EDIT:
This is the stack trace as requested:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff75de700 (LWP 3842)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ddd700 (LWP 3843)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff65dc700 (LWP 3844)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5ddb700 (LWP 3845)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff55da700 (LWP 3846)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff4dd9700 (LWP 3847)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff45d8700 (LWP 3848)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff3dd7700 (LWP 3849)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff65dc700 (LWP 3844)]
0x000000000041c8bf in std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_bucket_index (this=0x7fffffffde10, __p=0xc0, __n=467) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable_policy.h:793
793       { return _M_h2()(__p->_M_hash_code, __n); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000041c8bf in std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_bucket_index (this=0x7fffffffde10, __p=0xc0, __n=467)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable_policy.h:793
#1  0x0000000000419591 in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::_M_bucket_index (
    this=0x7fffffffde10, __n=0xc0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable.h:461
#2  0x000000000041561c in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::_M_find_before_node (
    this=0x7fffffffde10, __n=57, __k="bypass", __code=1325113244381254371) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable.h:1081
#3  0x0000000000410672 in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::_M_find_node (
    this=0x7fffffffde10, __bkt=57, __key="bypass", __c=1325113244381254371) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable.h:478
#4  0x000000000040c9e6 in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, Details>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, Details> >, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::find (this=0x7fffffffde10, __k=
    "bypass") at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/hashtable.h:939
#5  0x0000000000408e50 in InvertedIndex::addTerms (this=0x7fffffffdd00, parsedReport=...) at InvertedIndex.hpp:83
#6  0x00000000004091f2 in InvertedIndex::addReport (this=0x7fffffffdd00, fileName="/home/brodie/workspace/inverted_index/resources/test_reports/report6.xml") at InvertedIndex.hpp:104
#7  0x0000000000409e26 in InvertedIndex::loadIndex()::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const (__closure=0x6448e0) at InvertedIndex.hpp:169
#8  0x0000000000425128 in std::_Function_handler<void (), InvertedIndex::loadIndex()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) (__functor=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1926
#9  0x0000000000426ba4 in std::function<void ()>::operator()() const (this=0x6448b0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:2311
#10 0x0000000000426df1 in std::__invoke<std::function<void ()>>(std::function<void ()>&) (__f=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:235
#11 0x0000000000426dc6 in std::reference_wrapper<std::function<void ()> >::operator()<>() const (this=0x7ffff65dbcc0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:468
#12 0x0000000000426cc2 in std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<std::function<void ()> > ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x7ffff65dbcc0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1598
#13 0x0000000000426a3b in std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<std::function<void ()> > ()>::operator()() (this=0x7ffff65dbcc0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1586
#14 0x0000000000426717 in std::_Function_handler<void (), std::reference_wrapper<std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<std::function<void ()> > ()> > >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) (__functor=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1956
#15 0x0000000000426ba4 in std::function<void ()>::operator()() const (this=0x7fffd40008c8) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:2311
#16 0x000000000042681e in std::__future_base::_Task_setter<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result<void>, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter>, void>::operator() (this=0x7fffd40008c0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:1236
#17 0x0000000000426587 in std::_Function_handler<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> (), std::__future_base::_Task_setter<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result<void>, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter>, void> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) (__functor=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1912
#18 0x000000000040bde5 in std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>::operator()() const (this=0x7ffff65dbce0)
#19 0x0000000000408568 in std::__future_base::_State_base::_M_do_set(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&) (this=0x644838,
    __f=..., __set=@0x7ffff65dbc1f: false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:473
#20 0x000000000041b403 in std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&)>::operator()(std::__future_base::_State_base*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&) const (this=0x7ffff65dbba8, __object=0x644838,
    __args#0=..., __args#1=@0x7ffff65dbc1f: false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:554
#21 0x00000000004184fb in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&)> (std::__future_base::_State_base*, std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >, std::reference_wrapper<bool>)>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>) (this=0x7ffff65dbb90) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1598
#22 0x000000000041429f in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&)> (std::__future_base::_State_base*, std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >, std::reference_wrapper<bool>)>::operator()() (this=0x7ffff65dbb90) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1586
#23 0x000000000040fa7f in std::__once_call_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&)> (std::__future_base::_State_base*, std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >, std::reference_wrapper<bool>)> >() () at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/mutex:787
#24 0x00000036e920cac0 in pthread_once () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_once.S:103
#25 0x0000000000404266 in __gthread_once (__once=0x6448a4, __func=0x403eb0 <__once_proxy@plt>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:718
#26 0x000000000040bc8d in std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&), std::__future_base::_State_base* const, std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >, std::reference_wrapper<bool> >(std::onc---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
e_flag&, void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&), std::__future_base::_State_base* const&&, std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >&&, std::reference_wrapper<bool>&&) (__once=...,
    __f=<unknown type in /home/brodie/workspace/inverted_index/src/InvertedIndexMain, CU 0x0, DIE 0x3f48a>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/mutex:819
#27 0x0000000000408333 in std::__future_base::_State_base::_M_set_result(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>, bool) (this=0x644838, 
    __res=..., __ignore_failure=false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:362
#28 0x0000000000425f92 in std::__future_base::_Task_state<void ()>::_M_run() (this=0x644838) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:1271
#29 0x0000000000425c9c in std::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()() (this=0x644928) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/future:1379
#30 0x0000000000425ad8 in any_packaged<void>::execute (this=0x644920) at ThreadPool.hpp:27
#31 0x0000000000408743 in any_packaged_task::operator() (this=0x7ffff65dbdd0) at ThreadPool.hpp:40
#32 0x0000000000404baf in Worker::operator() (this=0x641120) at ThreadPool.hpp:109
#33 0x0000000000426068 in std::_Bind_simple<Worker ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x641120) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1598
#34 0x0000000000425cb9 in std::_Bind_simple<Worker ()>::operator()() (this=0x641120) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/functional:1586
#35 0x0000000000425af6 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Worker ()> >::_M_run() (this=0x641108) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/thread:115
#36 0x00000036ec6b2a20 in std::(anonymous namespace)::execute_native_thread_routine (__p=<optimized out>) at ../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:73
#37 0x00000036e9207d15 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff65dc700) at pthread_create.c:308
#38 0x00000036e8ef246d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:114
```

Comment: This is __not__ the actual code. Expect the same answer.

Comment: There's over 1000 lines of real code, this is what I've pinned the problem to be at. This is the only area where these variables are accessed.

Comment: What do you need `string term;` for? You are hiding it by `auto term = ...`.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. I can think of two possible options 1) your `std::string` implements COW or some other optimisation which is not thread safe (unlikely) 2) Problem is in the code you haven't shown us (more likely)

Comment: Mind you that a segmentation fault does not necessarily originate from the location where it finally occurs. Nevertheless consider posting the actual stacktrace from gdb.

Comment: Okay, I posted the stack trace. If there's any more code that will help I can post that too.

Comment: why are you passing `pair<string, list<string>>` by value? That looks like it's doing a ton of copying.

Comment: No reason specifically, it would be better to pass by reference I think. Just got hung up on this seg fault stuff in the meantime. I'll make that change in my code tho :-)

Comment: Note that your code isn't exception-safe : The mutex will remain locked if anything between the lock and unlock throws. But, this is unlikely to be the cause of four SIGSEGV

Comment: You should _never_ "lock operation foo", you should lock access to the structure. So (by the names) this looks fishy. And not seeing everything else that could mess around with your data structure, there is no way to diagnose anything.

Comment: @Roddy I did not know that, I'll try to fix it up. Thank you!

Comment: @vonbrand ya that's what I started to do but then moved it out to where it is now when I was having problems with it. I'll put it back in to only lock access to the structure. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but I have many unordered_maps (about 40k maps). I've noticed that, when a crash happens, there are always two threads roughly at that same point in code, but they're always processing different unordered_map's (each one has its own lock).

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `mutex` type isn't actually providing mutual exclusion. Did you remember to use the `-pthread` compiler flag?

Comment: I actually didn't, I was compiling with **g++ -Wall -c "%f" -std=c++0x -lxerces-c -lconfig++** then added the pthread flag per your suggestion **g++ -Wall -c "%f" -std=c++0x -lxerces-c -lconfig++ -pthread** and the trace seems to show the same problem.